# typeahead.js - Not sending query to 'remote' location

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, typeahead.js

I have typeahead.js from source:

https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js

The following example does not fire a request to the server side script for querying the database:

HTML:

```
<input id="doc" class="typeahead" type="text" placeholder="search here">
```

JS

```
$('#doc').typeahead({
  name: 'doc-search',
  minLength: 3,
  limit: 10,
  remote: '/Search&doc_no=%QUERY'
});
```

I don't see any calls being made to `/Search` in the developer console.

Comment: for anyone interested the typeahead.js projects is pretty much dead in terms of support: https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/1562

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.typeahead` doesn't contain definition for `remote` you need to use `Bloodhound` to fetch data remotely.

Here is an example of how you can fetch data remotely.

```
var docs = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('YourColumnName'),
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  remote: {
    remote: '/Search&doc_no=%QUERY',
    wildcard: '%QUERY'
  }
});

$('#doc').typeahead(null, {
  name: 'documents',
  display: 'value',
  source: docs
});
```

You can see `Remote` section of [examples](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/) page.

Comment: Thanks, I made the changes above but still nothing int he developer tools or server logs to show a request to `/Search`

Comment: @Dr.Avalanche please see the update. You need to use `Bolodhound` to fetch remote data.

Comment: Thanks, missing comma at the end of `remote: '/Search&doc_no=%QUERY'` but it works.

Comment: One more thing `display@ `value'` should match the value in `YourColumnName`